# CMake generated file causes compiling to fail

Tags: cmake

I am using CMake version 2.8.10.2. 
In one of the build.make files it's generating a version.h file by echoing the contents of the file. This is the command:

```
echo \#define QGSVERSION \"1c2b025\" >C:/dev/cpp/Quantum-build/qgsversion.h
```

It ends up in the .h file as

```
\#define  QGSVERSION \"1c2b025\"
```

When compiling, I get errors about `stray '\' in program`.

It's the `\#` before the define that is the problem. It looks like CMake wants to escape the `#` with a `\`. How do I work around this?

Comment: Could you please explain what you want to do rather than how you did it? Because echoing file seems wrong to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem in the provided CMakeLIst.txt file.
In the CMakeList.txt file it was stated

```
\\\#define QGSVERSION \\\"${REVISION}\\\" >${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/qgsversion.h
```

Where it should have been

```
\#define QGSVERSION \"${REVISION}\" >${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/qgsversion.h
```

The escape sequences was not correct.